# Combining file, grid and relationships

Tags: relationships, grid

Im trying to archieve the following, but somehow im missing something wich i can't figure out.

Basiscly, this is my setup:

I have an entry relationship with a grid field, wich contains a file/image.

And this is the syntax im trying to use. So far im able to get the grid field ouput, but i can't figure out how to show any file output.

This is my syntax:
showcase = relationship field
showcase afbeelding = grid field
cf_afbeelding = file field.

```
{showcase}   
            <ul>
            {showcase:showcase_afbeelding}   

                    {showcase_afbeelding:cf_afbeelding}

                        <li>  </li>                             
                    {/showcase_afbeelding:cf_afbeelding}

            {/showcase:showcase_afbeelding}
        </ul>
  {/showcase}

{showcase_afbeelding:cf_afbeelding} //works

{showcase_afbeelding:cf_afbeelding}
   {showcase_afbeelding:cf_afbeelding:path} //doesn't work.
{/showcase_afbeelding:cf_afbeelding}
```

Answer (score 1):

What would happen if you used:

```
{showcase}   
            <ul>
            {showcase:showcase_afbeelding}   

                    {showcase_afbeelding:cf_afbeelding}
                        //{URL} is the tag to spit out the location
                        <li>{url}</li>

                        //Not sure if you need to wrap in these tags 
                        <li>{showcase_afbeelding:cf_afbeelding:url}</li>
                    {/showcase_afbeelding:cf_afbeelding}

            {/showcase:showcase_afbeelding}
        </ul>
  {/showcase}
```

Comment: Doesn't work... I tried most variants.